# Php Db synchronization

Tags: php, schema, migration, mysql

I have a local server where I do all my testing and work. Once I am done, I simply upload the db schema along with the relevant code. However the problem arises when I make some changes to the schema. I have to manually type the "alter table" query on my live server.

Is there a way to get the incremental changes that took place in the db schema so that I can just apply the new ones? Or do I have to manually keep track?

If I use mysqldump, then it produces the schema of the final db (not with alter table etc).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html) lets you export ALTER scripts (File -> Export -> Forward Engineer SQL ALTER Script). You'll have first to import your existing database and apply your modifications to it. The commercial version lets you reverse engineer a live database, the community one does it importing a CREATE script instead (this would be a simple dump of the existing structure). Alternatively you can reverse engineer a live database with [DBDesigner 4](http://www.fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/), save all to an XML Model file end import this, but you're gonna lose stuff like the default charset and such...

Answer (score 2):

I keep the delta sql scripts which go to the production server together with the new code. I script everything so the change of the application from version X to version Y is "automatic". [Some people also have undo scripts](http://www.se-radio.net/podcast/2008-09/episode-109-ebay039s-architecture-principles-randy-shoup) in case something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

How about storing off the changes that you did in development, test those changes as a group to live?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/).  It's Java, but it works fairly well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool for automation process^ http://hg.antonoff.info/idler/mmp/wiki/Home

Requirement only PHP (but version >= 5.3)